# Suppose a matrix $A \in \text{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F}_5)$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2 - x +1$. Is $A$ diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_5$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Suppose a matrix $A \in \text{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{F}_5)$ has characteristic polynomial $x^2 - x +1$. Is $A$ diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_5$?

Normally, I would just check to see if the geometric multiplicity and algebraic multiplicity are equal for each eigenspace, but over $\mathbb{F}_5$, I am not even sure what the eigenvalues are!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The char polynomial has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_5$, so the matrix is not diagonalizable over that field. It is diagonalizable over $\Bbb{F}_{25}$ because the char polynomial has two different roots in that field.

Comment: Is there a general result you are using?

Comment: As you noted: all eigenvalues must belong to the field and geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue is equal to its algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: What roots does the polynomial have in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$? I cannot find any.

Comment: The polynomial has degree 2 over $\Bbb{F}_5$ and no roots in that field, so it has two roots in an extension of degree $2$, there is only one such extension, $\Bbb{F}_{25}$. The roots are different because  the derivative $2x-1$ has only one root, $x=3 \mod 5$ which is not a root of $x^2-x+1$.

Answer (score 3):

If your matrix were diagonalizable, then there would be a diagonal matrix $$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{bmatrix} \in \text{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb F_5)$$ with the same characteristic polynomial. But then, $\Lambda^2 - \Lambda + I = 0_{2\times 2}$ implies $\lambda_i^2  - \lambda_i + 1 = 0$ for $i=1,2$, and there are no such elements in $\mathbb F_5$.